# Push notifications are not working in updated version from ios7 to ios8.1

Tags: push-notification, ios8, apple-push-notifications, xcode6, ios8.1

I updated my device from ios7 to ios8.1.Push notifications are not working in updated version.
I did same process for push notifications which is done in ios7.
The code is also updated

```
    #ifdef __IPHONE_8_0
      //Right, that is the point
        UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeBadge
    |UIUserNotificationTypeSound
    |UIUserNotificationTypeAlert) categories:nil];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
#else
    //register to receive notifications
    UIRemoteNotificationType myTypes = UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:myTypes];
#endif
```

By using the above code also i didnot get notification.Please help me for push notifications in ios8.1.

thanks inadvance

Answer (score 3):

The method for receiving a push notification has also changed:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleActionWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier
```

See [Handling Local and Remote Notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html) and [UIApplicationDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiapplicationdelegate_protocol/index.html) for more info.

Here is a full example of an application delegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {
        NSLog(@"Requesting permission for push notifications..."); // iOS 8
        UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:
            UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge |
            UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil];
        [UIApplication.sharedApplication registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Registering device for push notifications..."); // iOS 7 and earlier
        [UIApplication.sharedApplication registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
            UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge |
            UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound];
    }
    return YES;
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
    didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)settings
{
    NSLog(@"Registering device for push notifications..."); // iOS 8
    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
    didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)token
{
    NSLog(@"Registration successful, bundle identifier: %@, device token: %@",
        [NSBundle.mainBundle bundleIdentifier], token);
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
    didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Failed to register: %@", error);
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleActionWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier
    forRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)notification completionHandler:(void(^)())completionHandler
{
    NSLog(@"Received push notification: %@, identifier: %@", notification, identifier); // iOS 8
    completionHandler();
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
    didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)notification
{
    NSLog(@"Received push notification: %@", notification); // iOS 7 and earlier
}
```

Comment: not working in my case ? i don't find any doc regarding these new changes? please give some useful link